# How to use array.includes without any or ignore?

Tags: typescript

Given an array of strings: ie

```
const foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'].
```

How can I type `foo.includes` such that `foo.includes(1)` returns false and TS does not throw an error, without using `any` or `@ts-ignore`

The error I receive is `Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`, which yes, I agree, but it should still allow it.

I 100% understand that yes, I have an array of `strings` and of course passing in a `number` will return false, but this should still be typesafe.

I've tried many options to no avail

Ideally I would hope there would be away to use some generic type or something that I'm missing in order to type this safely without `any` or ignoring.

Comment: Are you actually typing `foo.includes(1)` or `foo.includes(myVar)` where myVar is a Number? Can't you check the type of `myVar` before calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could type your array to include number

```
const foo: Array<string | number> = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you! this looks to be it!

What I was missing originally was setting `foo` to `string | number`, to allow `.includes` to not complain.

makes total sense now

Comment: I am a bit sad however at TS, because I feel like I should be able to say `foo.includes( anything )`

In addition to above, I feel like I should be able to say `foo.includes(true)`.  

In order for TS to not complain, I'd have to type ```foo: Array<string | number | boolean>```, which technically feels weird as my original intention was to have an array of `string`.  :(

Comment: What is the point of strongly typing a data structure only to allow it to pass any type you want?

Comment: `foo` is not an array that can ever include a number. So maybe a solution is: `const isIncluded = typeof 4 === 'string' && ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(4)`. However my solution here isn't a solution, because in another case, (ie:  array includes a union of values), its not easy to use javascript to typecheck it before trying `.includes`